# Run Android Studio with Java 8

Tags: android-studio

Since a plugin for IntelliJ (Upsource) requires Java 8 I'd like to run my Android Studio with Java 8 on a Mac. 
I could setup JAVA_HOME and start Android Studio from terminal but this is very inconvenient. I'd like to start Android Studio from the OSX UI. 
I did not find a way how to specify the JAVA_HOME with Android Studio settings. Moreover this link (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) says nothing about Android Studio.

Does anyone know where to configure the Runtime-JDK/JRE for Android Studio 2.1 on OSX without setting any JAVA_HOME?

Comment: I'm pretty sure android studio setup asks you for your Java directory

Comment: That might be. But I've already installed it and would like to avoid a reinstallation.

Comment: Did you try setting your SDK by File > Project Structure > [Platform Settings] > SDKs ?

Comment: This is the project SDK, not the SDK/JRE Android Studio is started with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

> export STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk

You can also have a look here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration/osx-jdk it explains how to set the jre for running android-studio and the jdk for your android project.

In short, you can in a terminal:

```
export STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

And it will launch android_studio with the jdk8

EDIT: from comment @Soccertrash

You can persist the STUDIO_JDK variable via launchctl:

```
launchctl setenv STUDIO_JDK /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>
```

Comment: Please explain what this does and where to put it so not only we help the OP better but the future visitors.

Comment: Your suggestion did work. But how can I set the Studio_JDK without opening Android Studio via terminal?

Comment: I'm not a mac user, but maybe you can set that somehow in the Android\ Studio.app ?

Comment: my expectation is that i can setup the SDK in those vm or custum properties files, but this did not work

Comment: Indeed you can't, it's too late at that point, the jre is already launched

Comment: I added the variable via launchctl: launchctl setenv STUDIO_JDK /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>